# How to match/find a string by Regular Expression

Tags: regex

Here is my regular expression:

```
(?is)(\b\w+\b)(?:,\s*'[^']*',\s*'[^']*'\))?\s*\bas\b\s*\bdisplay_text\b
```

Currently its just matching `field2` from the following strings.

1. `SELECT DISTINCT field1 AS value, field2 AS display_text`
2. `SELECT DISTINCT replace(field1, ',', '/') AS value, replace(field2, ',', '/') AS display_text`

I need a regular expression that can match `field2` from 1st statement and `replace(field2, ',', '/')` from 2nd statement.

Please anyone help me to create this regular expression.

Comment: [Now you have two problems](http://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/)...

Comment: It appears you want to parse SQL, why not use a SQL parser? (We need to know why you've rejected this approach because it gives us information about the significant details of the problem.)

Comment: I never understand why people think that regex is the solution to every problem in the world, and end up creating crazy complex expressions that are impossible to read and debug, when there is a much simpler solution to the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add an optional pattern to match the beginning `replace(` string.

```
(?is)\b(?:\S+\()?\b\w+\b(?:,\s*'[^']*',\s*'[^']*'\))?(?=\s*\bas\b\s*\bdisplay_text\b)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/jA7eF0/1)